# Do all UWP apps work on Windows 10 IoT?

Tags: windows-iot

Is it possible to use all UWP apps on Windows 10 IoT.

Comment: IIRC no as there are some libs not available/supported on the Pi version.

Comment: Hi - What is UWT app? Do you mean Windows Universal App (UWA)  Windows 8 API or Windows Universal Platform (UWP) for Window 10 API?

Comment: Hi, I meant UWP.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your question or find any answer?

Answer (score 2):

I want to say **Yes**

All UWP (Universal Windows Platform) applications are designed to run on all Windows 10 API compatible paltforms, including IoT.

**But** the fact you are asking about this, is scaring me because you may have a UWP that does not work on the 10IoT for some reason??

> There are as of writing 3 different API's versions too.. you may need
>   to use the correct OS with the correct API Level

UWP is made for the Windows 10 API ecosystem. UWP also runs on the XBox, Hololens, Surface hub, and "other" compatible OS's

*As long as the compiled application is truly 100% Universal Platform then even graphical output will work on the Pi. Albeit the Pi does not have a HardDirectX driver yet and using soft translations.. which also means no h264 streaming. (May 2017) but neither do many other Linux distros*

[image]

[*More information can be found here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **NO**.

The following are two reasons that readily come to mind about why a Universal Windows Application may not really be universal.

1. **Completeness of Implementation:**
   UWP encompasses a set of universal framework which is designed such that applications can be ran on all platforms that support UWA (Universal Windows Apps). There are, however, varying degrees of 'completeness' of implementation of UWP. For example, UWP on Windows 10 IoT Core (the version for Raspberry Pi) [does not support the FileOpenPicker](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a6db19f-2dfb-46e6-bd0f-2749506e318b/fileopenpicker-availability-on-windows-10-iot?forum=WindowsIoT) and so UWP apps that use it (and other similar dialogs) cannot be expected to work properly.
2. **Bridged Applications:**
   Likewise, if an existing WinForms or WPF application is converted to UWP using the Desktop Bridge with no further modifications, all the underlying calls remain the same with no calls to the universal ones provided by the UWP. These applications aren't true UWA. They are effectively Windows Desktop applications *'disguised'* to appear to be UWA. Such applications will not work on platforms except Windows Desktop.